# Why getting unexpected with loop of URL results when solving equation

Tags: java, web-crawler, equation

I am trying to write a web crawler algorithm. To do that i use the equations below:

[image]

and i write this code too to solve it:

```
public class URLWeight {


public static List<LinkNode> weight(LinkNode sourceLink, List<LinkNode> links){

    List<LinkNode> interLinks = new LinkedList<>();
    List<LinkNode> intraLinks = new LinkedList<>();


    for (LinkNode link : links) {
        if(isIntraLink(sourceLink, link)) { 
            intraLinks.add(link);
        } else {
            interLinks.add(link);
        }
    }


    if(interLinks.size()>intraLinks.size()) {
      // finding inter weight
      for (LinkNode link : interLinks) {
          link.setWeight(((interLinks.size() + intraLinks.size())-intraLinks.size())/(interLinks.size() + intraLinks.size())*(2/3f));
      }

      // finding intra weight

      for (LinkNode link : intraLinks) {
              link.setWeight(((interLinks.size() + intraLinks.size())-intraLinks.size())/(interLinks.size() + intraLinks.size())*(1/3f));
        }
    }


    //////*//////


    else
    if(interLinks.size()<intraLinks.size()) {
      //inter puan
      for (LinkNode link : interLinks) {
          link.setWeight(((interLinks.size() + intraLinks.size())-interLinks.size())/(interLinks.size() + intraLinks.size())*(2/3f));
      }

      // intra puan
      for (LinkNode link : intraLinks) {
      link.setWeight(((interLinks.size() + intraLinks.size())-interLinks.size())/(interLinks.size() + intraLinks.size())*(1/3f));
    }

    }

    List<LinkNode> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.addAll(interLinks);
    list.addAll(intraLinks);

    return list;
}
```

The program is running without error but am getting wrong results and all of results are getting me 0.0 with loop of URL results. The program will start crawling with a seed URL then it will divide the links into two groups (inter and intra), then it will compare the size of (inter and intra) and try to use the equations from 1 to 4 to get each inter and intra links results. Then sort the weight of each link in the frontier then in the next step it will select the highest weight to be seed URL for the next step. But the program should is stack in some places and getting me the same URLs not crawl any link more than one time. And here is some of results i've got:

```
http://www.example.edu ---> 

    http://www.iaeng.org/IMECS2015/ICDMA2015.html 
    http://www.example.edu/contacts.html -- 0.0 
    http://sdiwc.net/conferences/2014/bigdata2014/ -- 0.0 
    http://sdiwc.net/conferences/2014/icctim2014/ -- 0.0 
    http://www2014.wwwconference.org/sub2_1.php -- 0.0 
    http://example.edu/?language=en_US -- 0.0 
    http://www.sanayi.gov.tr/Default.aspx?lng=en -- 0.0    
    http://www.huawei.com/tr/ -- 0.0 
    https://www.tai.com.tr/tr -- 0.0 
    http://www.example.edu/courses.html -- 0.0 
    http://www.example.edu/index.html -- 0.0 
    http://www.example.edu/people.html -- 0.0 
    http://www.example.edu/projects.html -- 0.0 
    http://www.example.edu/publications.html -- 0.0     
    http://www.example.edu/research.html -- 0.0 15 

http://www.iaeng.org/IMECS2015/ICDMA2015.html ---> 

    http://www.example.edu/contacts.html -- 0.0
    http://www.example.edu/research.html -- 0.0 
    http://sdiwc.net/conferences/2014/bigdata2014/ -- 0.0  
    http://sdiwc.net/conferences/2014/icctim2014/ -- 0.0 
    http://www2014.wwwconference.org/sub2_1.php -- 0.0 
    http://example.edu/?language=en_US -- 0.0  
    http://www.sanayi.gov.tr/Default.aspx?lng=en -- 0.0  
    http://www.huawei.com/tr/ -- 0.0 
    https://www.tai.com.tr/tr -- 0.0 
    http://www.example.edu/courses.html -- 0.0 
    http://www.example.edu/index.html -- 0.0 
    http://www.example.edu/people.html -- 0.0 
    http://www.example.edu/projects.html -- 0.0   
    http://www.example.edu/publications.html -- 0.0
```

Can you figure were am doing wrong or what should i do to solve this problem ? problem point ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is you are using integer division from all the .size() methods which will result in 0 if the answer is less than 1. Cast your results of .size() to float or double

Comment: Can you suggest me how to casting the .size() to float or double please ? BTW .. i am getting cloned results too can you tell me why ? Thanks

Comment: @medo0070 (float)interLinks.size()

Comment: you mean changing the equations to be like this: 
     link.setWeight((((float)interLinks.size() + (float)intraLinks.size())-(float)intraLinks.size())/((float)interLinks.size() + (float)intraLinks.size())*(2/3f)); ?

Comment: i did it its works but i am still getting 0.0 in a half of results. i mean it is not fixed all 0.0 Can you tell me were am doing wrong? i did change for all equations 1,2,3 and 4

Comment: 0 might not be a wrong answer if there are really 0 interlinks or intralinks. That would cause the equation answer to be 0.

Comment: Thanks .. i solved the first part of the problem which is getting 0.0 **(with type casting)** . But still getting **clone URL crawling** i think its a problem with `if` and `for` but i did not recognize it @nitegazer2003